# What is "-srvcert" in OpenSSL cmp command line?

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure, openssl

I use the following command to get a signed certificate from PKI.

What is the content of the file srvcert.crt of the option -srvcert ?
It seems the srvcert.crt file is not the public certificate of the pki_server. Indeed, I tried with it and it does not work.

```
openssl cmp -cmd ir -server pki_server:8040 \
-path signing-cmp/test -cert /tmp/mycert.crt \
-key /tmp/mycert.key -newkey /tmp/new.key \
-subject '/C=FR/CN=domain.com/ST=London/L=London/O=Organization/OU=IT Administration' \
-certout /tmp/new.crt -srvcert /tmp/srvcert.crt
```

Here is how got the public certificate of the PKI. The option -srvcert does not work with this file.

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect pki_server:443 \
    2>/dev/null  | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/srvcert.crt
```

Comment: What version of openssl do you use? My installation (1.1.1c  on Ubuntu) doesn't have `cmp`.

Comment: This is an extension of openssl.

Comment: https://github.com/mpeylo/cmpossl

Answer (score 1):

I am citing from [man openssl-cmp](https://github.com/mpeylo/cmpossl/blob/cmp/doc/man1/cmp.pod)

> #### Server authentication options
>
> ...
>   **-srvcert filename**
>       The specific CMP server certificate to use and directly trust (even if it is expired) when verifying signature-based protection of CMP response messages. May be set alternatively to the **-trusted** option if the certificate is available and only this one shall be accepted.

So this option is used to authenticate the server but is not *required*.

The  example for enrollment in this man page does have a shared secret between server and client but does not use `-srvcert` at all.

> ```
> openssl cmp -cmd ir -server 127.0.0.1:8080 -path pkix/ \
>    -ref 1234 -secret pass:1234-5678-1234-5678 \
>    -recipient "/CN=CMPserver" \
>    -newkey cl_key.pem -subject "/CN=MyName" \
>    -cacertsout capubs.pem -certout cl_cert.pem
> ```

My suggestion **for now** would be to omit server authentication and test if everything else works.